# How to find duplicate between staging and main table with millions records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `mysql` and I want to check the duplicate rows between two tables. I used `join` but it's taking too much time as there are millions of records (for example staging table has 800k records while the main table has around 100 million records).

The query I am using is as follow :

```
INSERT INTO 
    tblspduplicate
SELECT 
    T2.SP,T1.FileImportedDate,T2.XYZFileName 
FROM  
    tblspmaster T1
INNER JOIN 
    tblstaging T2 
ON 
    T1.SP=T2.SP;

CREATE TABLE `tblspmaster` (
  `CSN` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SP` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FileImportedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `XYZFileName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `XYZBatch` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BatchProcessedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FCCity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7484570 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `tblstaging` (
  `CSN` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SP` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FileImportedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `XYZFileName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `XYZBatch` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BatchProcessedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FCCity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSN`),
  KEY `ind_staging` (`SP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=851956 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the schema of the tables, along with their additional indexes (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an index on `tblspmaster.SP`?  That would be the most important thing.  With such an index, you query should be ok.  First, though, test the query on using just the `select`.

Another problem that you could have are duplicate matches.  This might be significantly multiplying the data that you have.  You can test for this by doing:

```
select sp, count(*) as cnt
from tblmaster
group by sp
having cnt > 1
order by cnt desc;
```

and

```
select sp, count(*) as cnt
from tblstaging
having cnt > 1
order by cnt desc;
```

EDIT:

Based on the table structure, I repeat the suggestion to create an index to `tblMaster(SP)`.  You may also need to drop the index on `tblStaging(SP)`.  Alternatively, you can force the use of the master index instead of the staging index by using an index hint (the simple syntax is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html)).

Also, I suggest that you run the above counts to see the risk of getting an unexpectedly large number of rows because of multiplicity in the SP values.

Comment: there is already a column named CSN which is auto increment and its necessary to make that column as key .

Comment: and i have unique index on this column name `SP` to make sure `SP` always remain unique in this table .

Comment: @rahularyansharma . . . If you have a unique index on SP in both tables, the `select` query should have reasonable performance.

Comment: I have dropped the unique index but stil its taking so much time .should i paste my both table schema also here .

Comment: Hello sir , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692078/update-exported-records-using-into-outfile is it possible ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you case use INTERSECt SQL, but I don't now khow many time he can take.

Comment: MySQL does not support `INTERSECT`.